# How to quickly search for a symbol under cursor in all project files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

While browsing through C++ code in VS Code, I am looking for a better way (possibly just a simple keyboard shortcut after some configuration) to do the following:

1. My cursor is hovering over a symbol (e.g. `MyClass` class).
2. I want to search for this symbol in all project files (i.e. perform Ctrl + Shift + F search on the symbol under cursor)

At present I don't know a better way then to copy the symbol name -> Ctrl + Shift + F -> paste the name -> hit 'Enter'.

Answer (score 8):

As of version 1.42.0 there is no single-keystroke way of doing it (although I would appreciate this very much).

You could use the sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.
("Add Selection To Next Find Match")

Better: There is an extension exactly for this use case, it's called:
"Search Under Cursor"

Comment: Ctrl-D is used for my Vim plugin config for `Page Down` : (

Answer (score 2):

I added a single keychord method to my extension: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  So if you set up a keybinding like:

```
{
    "key": "alt+z",      // whatever keybinding you like
    "command": "runInSearchPanel"
}
```

you can trigger the keychord when the cursor is on (or immediately after) a word or select a word and the Search Panel will open with that word as the query.

[image: run a search with no arguments]

---

The command can also take a lot of arguments, like:

```
{
    "key": "alt+z",
    "command": "runInSearchPanel",
    "args": {
        "find": "(?<=^Arturo)\\d+",   // fixed-width lookbehinds and multiline supported
        "replace": "###",
        "matchWholeWord": false,
        "isRegex": true,
        "filesToInclude": "${file}",  // resolves to current file
        "triggerSearch": true
    }
}
```

and other `args` if you want to save a pre-defined search as a keybinding or as a setting that will be exposed in the Command Palette.  More at the README.

Demo of keybinding with arguments immediately above:

[image: search with pre-defined arguments]

---

Previous Answer:

You don't have to copy or paste the symbol, just highlight all of it.  You can do that in various ways such as double-clicking the word or I like the  [vscode expand region extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region).  Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to perform the search.

This is assuming you have

> // Controls if we seed the search string in Find Widget from editor selection
>
> "editor.find.seedSearchStringFromSelection": true,

in your settings.  true is the default.

[ Apologies to @yorammi if this is what you said, I couldn't follow your instructions ... ]

Comment: this answer did not work for me. installed the extension, and specified the key binding command including the ```args```, left the cursor in the middle of a word, then 'alt+z', ended up with a search bar with text ```(?<=^Arturo)\d+```, regular expression 'enabled', and replace text bar with text ```###```.

Comment: @Steve I added a couple of gifs for the two keybindings above.  Do you see something different from what is happening in the second example?  (Make sure you are on v3.3.3 of the extension, I found a bug for the first, non-arg version of the keybinding which is already fixed).  Did you modify the args?  Thanks.

Comment: v3.3.3 wasn't installable for me. I currently am on v3.3.2, I can downgrade, but cannot upgrade: Install Another Version... -> clicked 'v3.3.3' -> nothing happened

Comment: @Steve Yes, that has happened to me, including just now.  But it worked on the third try - it seems to take awhile to realize that a new version has been installed and tell you  to do a reload.  I would just do a reload after attempting to install.

Answer (score 0):

Click and hold the `Shift` key when hover the symbol.
The text should be changed to be with underscore and in different color and then - without releasing the `shift` - click the symbol.